# Half circle gradient js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to get the gradient effect in the circle? I have such an [initial code](https://jsfiddle.net/cv67a1Lj/1/):

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="progresss">
   <div class="barOverflow">
     <div class="bar"></div>
   </div>
   <span>10</span>%
 </div>

 <div class="progresss">
   <div class="barOverflow">
     <div class="bar"></div>
   </div>
   <span>75</span>%
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.progresss{
    position: relative;
    margin: 4px;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
}
.barOverflow{ /* Wraps the rotating .bar */
    position: relative;
    //overflow: hidden; /* Comment this line to understand the trick */
    width: 145px; height: 45px; /* Half circle (overflow) */
    margin-bottom: -14px; /* bring the numbers up */

    &:after {
        content: '';
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        top: -75px;
        width: 145px;
        height: 90px;
        background-color: #f3f5f6;
    }
}
    .bar{
    position: relative;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 145px; height: 145px; /* full circle! */
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 27px solid red;       /* half red, */
    border-bottom-color: green;  /* half green */
    border-right-color: green;

}
```

**JS:**

```
$(".progresss").each(function(){

  var $bar = $(this).find(".bar");
  var $val = $(this).find("span");
  var perc = parseInt( $val.text(), 10);

  $({p:0}).animate({p:perc}, {
    duration: 3000,
    easing: "swing",
    step: function(p) {
      $bar.css({
        transform: "rotate("+ (45+(p*1.8)) +"deg)", // 100%=180° so: ° = % * 1.8
        // 45 is to add the needed rotation to have the green borders at the     bottom
      });
      $val.text(p|0);
    }
  });
});
```

what I want is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar back in the day and as I discovered that only way to implement gradient border was (and I guess still is) using [CSS border-image property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp), I came up with completely different approach:

1. Create 3 nested `div` elements:

   - `wrapper`, which we need to hide the overflow,
   - `out`, which is the one with gradient `background` color - that's the one we are going to rotate,
   - `in`, which is the inner circle **on** which growing percentage numbers are displayed,
2. Inside first `wrapper` add some element to hold the percentage number and using `position: absolute`, place it in the middle of the parent: we do not display percentage in the `in` element, because it is rotating with `out` one, and it's easier to just create another element than synchronize rotation of two circles.
3. Make `wrapper` a circle and hide it's overflow - it helps in **4.:**
4. Give `out` element gradient background, bottom half green-ish, top half transparent - it is shaped as circle due to it's parent overflow.
5. Whole the rest is just math: **you can check it out in [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s863zk8j/)**.

It is not perfect solution and I would not mind posting it in case where you used percentage `width` and `height`. But, as I saw fixed (`px`) dimensions I thought that you can use my approach as well.

It is all matter of adjusting it to your needs - gradient as well as dimensions, and if you have trouble positioning the whole thing, just do it with `wrapper` element, and children will "follow".